# Binding an int into TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, int

I copied this code from the other question. It should work, but it failed in my try. Can any one tell me why? thanks!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Unit");

    }

    private int unit;
    public event EventHandler UnitChanged; // or via the "Events" list
    public int Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (value != unit)
            {
                unit = value;
                EventHandler handler = UnitChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Unit++;
    }
```

Comment: @Koen: `value` is the value that has been set for this property!

Comment: In the code you supplied, the Unit Property is never accessed.If you change "unit++" to "this.Unit++" the setter code in the property will execute. So do us all a favor: either post all your code, give a better description of your problem, or try an easier example. I guess you noticed the down votes?

Comment: UnitChanged needs to do something if I'm not wrong?

Comment: @IsThatSo: You are right.. in the code supplied, he doesn't subscribe to the event.. That's why I suggested he sends the full code... Or try something simpler... :)

Comment: @weePee There is no other code needed. He was just incrementing the backing field instead of the property.

Comment: @weePee & Rufus YES, I had showed all my code. It's a test case to bind an int into a TextBox.

Comment: @IsThatSo I'll if I obtain the answer. However, It seems it's still up in the air. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing the private field (lowercase `unit`), rather than the property bound to the `TextBox` (uppercase `Unit`).

Try changing the code here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Unit++;
}
```

Comment: unit is increased, too. It's not shown in the textbox.

Comment: @IsThatSo Yes, of course. But the event handler is only called when `Unit` is changed (in the setter).

Comment: i think he needs the updated value to be shown in the textbox.

Comment: ah, sorry. I hadn't bind the form load event to form. +1 from me.

Comment: @Rufus I had tried Unit before I set out this question. It didn't work either.

Comment: @user3882074 it worked for me, too. please recheck if all the events are tied to appropriate elements.

Comment: @IsThatSo Thanks a lot! Do you mean the code listed above worked on your platform? or you mean you have some code which worked for you? I recreated a test project to try this code, and it still failed. Nothing shows (changes) when the unit (or Unit) changed. I am running VC# 2013 on Win 8.1

Comment: @user3882074 I copied/pasted your code into a WinForm project, changed the casing of `unit++` to `Unit++` in the `button1_Click` event, and it worked just fine.

Comment: @user3882074 same case with Rufus in my environment. Windows 8.1 Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Rufus Do you mean that the value of the textbook will be changed and showed when you pushed the button? If yes, would you send your whole test project in a zip file to garrychang@hotmail.com. Mine till failed. Thank you very much!